# swift2: repacking json dictionary into an array suitable for uitableview presentation

Tags: swift2, containers

I'm pretty sure there is a more compact way to rewrite this

```
func showResults(result : [NSObject : AnyObject]?) {
    var repacked = Array<(String!,String!)>()
    for(key, value) in result {
        let keyString: String! = key as! String
        let valueString: String! = value as! String
        if(key == "FrontRowKey") {
            repacked.insert((keyString,valueString), atIndex: 0)
        }else{
            repacked.append((keyString,valueString))
        }
    }
    ...
```

utilizing closures. Is there?
I assume if this code changes (to pluck aside a few elements out of the dictionary before repacking into an array of tuples) it'd have to stay unwrapped
like this or it still would be possible to map one container into another
using your proposed compact (closure based?) solution?

The use case: converting the data type returned by a datamodel for the subsequent presentation in UITableView[Controller]
so the first row would likely be a custom cell presenting one or a combination of a few entries into the dictionary

If there is no way to make this more compact could some of the ugliness
be eliminated or reduced here?

tnx

UPD with vadian's suggestions:

```
func tupleArray4UITableViewPresentationFromJSONDictionary(dict: [NSObject:AnyObject]) -> [(String, String)]
{
    var result = [(String, String)]()
    for(key, value) in dict {
        let keyString: String = key as! String
        var valueString: String = "implement me"
        if let s = value as? String {
            valueString = s
        }else   if let b = value as? NSNumber {
            valueString = b.stringValue
        }else   if let b = value as? NSNull {
            // I don't expect any of these and do not need to assert, but YOU might
            continue
        }else {
            assert("the rest are unsupported: uitableview is not capable of displaying a nested container" != nil)
        }
        key == "FrontRowKey" ? result.insert((keyString,valueString), atIndex: 0) : result.append((keyString,valueString))
        return result
}

func showResults(result : [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    let repacked = tupleArray4UITableViewPresentationFromJSONDictionary(result)
```

OR

```
func tupleArray4UITableViewPresentationFromJSONDictionary(dict: [NSObject:AnyObject]) -> [(String, String)]
{
    var result = [(String, String)]()
    for(key, value) in dict {
        let keyString: String = key as! String
        var valueString: String = "implement for values that do not conform to CustomStringConvertible"
        if let s = value as? CustomStringConvertible {
            valueString = "\(s)"
        }else  if let _ = value as? NSNull {
            // I don't expect any of these and do not need to assert, but YOU might
            continue
        }else {
            assert("the rest are unsupported: uitableview is not capable of displaying a nested container" != nil)
        }
        key == "FrontRowKey" ? result.insert((keyString,valueString), atIndex: 0) : result.append((keyString,valueString))
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: There are faaaaar to many `!`.

Comment: Why do you declare key and value in the destination array as optional since you forced unwrap them anyway and they couldn't be optional by definition? And why do you declare the source dictionary as `[NSObject:AnyObject]?` (optional) since you know it's `[String:String]` (non optional)? The key concept of Swift is to be as type specific and non optional as possible.

Comment: well, [NSObject : AnyObject]? is what objc->swift mapper shows as a type that is NSDictionary coming from the legacy objc code that feeds me json parsed into dictionary. So I guess I can't really assume let valueString: String! = value as! String and have to concoct some daisy chaining if let valueString: String! = value as! String ... or whatever

Comment: If you know the actual type cast the object to that type before processing it. By definition the keys and values of a dictionary must not be `nil`, so there is no need to treat them as optionals.

Comment: for keys I suppose I do. For values that's an issue: native json deserializer can return string, nsnumber, whatever. At least in objc space. I don't see why swift would be any different. I've added the code bastardized from your generic as an UPD to the original question. Thanks for clarifying my question. I wonder if it's a terrible idea if I;d clarify that the incoming dictionary comes from ios json deserializer

Comment: Not *whatever*. JSON can return `String`, `NSNumber`, `NSNull`  and the  collection types `Array` and `Dictionary`. The annotation as implicit unwrapped optional `let keyString: String! = key as! String` is useless because the key can never ever be `nil` in a dictionary and the key in a JSON dictionary is guaranteed to be `String`

Comment: gotcha. Updated the question title and the highly specialized helper that you've helped to devise. Let's see how helpful this will be to other folks on s.o. long term.  Thanks again for helping to clarify what the function is actually supposed to do as well as with the cleanup.

Comment: I added an alternative to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion using a generic:

```
func tupleArrayFromDictionary<V>(dict: [String:V]) -> [(String, V)]
{
  var result = [(String, V)]()
  for(key, value) in dict {
    key == "FrontRowKey" ? result.insert((key,value), atIndex: 0) : result.append((key,value))
  }
  return result
}
```

Alternatively you could constrain a JSON dictionary to `[String:CustomStringConvertible]` for example

```
func tupleArrayFromJSONDictionary(dict: [String:CustomStringConvertible]) -> [(String, String)]
{
  var result = [(String, String)]()
  for(key, value) in dict {
    key == "FrontRowKey" ? result.insert((key,"\(value)"), atIndex: 0) : result.append((key,"\(value)"))
  }
  return result
}

let dict : [String:CustomStringConvertible] = ["alpha" : "1", "beta" : 2, "FrontRowKey" : true]
let result = tupleArrayFromJSONDictionary(dict)
```

That doesn't cover collection types and `NSNull` but might be helpful for flat dictionaries